# Kendo + RequireJS + private jquery not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, requirejs

I am trying to use Kendo with requirejs and a private jquery.

The private jquery tip is documented [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html), Kendo with requirejs usage is [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/using-kendo-with-requirejs).

My requirejs config :

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js",
        "k": "js/kendo/2013.2.716"
    },
    map: {
        "*": {
            "jquery": "jquery-private",
        },
        "jquery-private": { "jquery": "jquery" },
    }
});
define("jquery-private", ["jquery"], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict(true);
});
```

Then when I `require(["jquery", "k/kendo.dropdown.min"], function(){...})`, I have errors.

I seams that Kendo is not able to work with a private jquery. Is there a way to make it work with a private jquery ? Is only some shim config needed ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? If it's a require.js related problem the errors will usually be accompanied by a pretty useful link pointing you to a possible solution.

Comment: Error is `Unable to get property 'extend' of undefined or null reference` in kendo.core.min.js.

Comment: Are you actually passing the dependencies to your function? Like `require(["jquery", "k/kendo.dropdown.min"], function($, kendodropdown){...})`

Comment: My actual code is a module defined with dependencies : `["jquery", "k/kendo.datepicker.min"]`. I have tryed to add some shim, I don't know if I have to set `"kendo.core.min" = {deps: ["jquery"]}` or `"k/kendo.core.min = ...`. I have other libs that does not like to be loaded with requirejs (bootstrap 3, signalr...) So I think I will give up trying to use a private jquery and use a global one. I just need to know why I have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571545/signalr-and-requirejs-client-methods-undefined).

Answer (score -1):

This is a pure guess since I do not even know what the kendo thing is, but I believe your problems stem from these issues:

```
//This require statement is not correct.
require(["jquery", "k/kendo.dropdown.min"], function(){...})
```

Your not binding jQuery to any variables so if you later try to use it it does not exists. You likely want something like this.

```
require(["jquery", "k/kendo.dropdown.min"], function($){
```

Another problem is that the kendo plugin likely assumes global jQuery. That means you have to ensure the plugin properly declares and binds its dependencies local variables. The plugin code should be wrapped into something like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
  ],
  function (jQuery) {
    //In case it also depends on the $ then set it up here too:
    var $ = jQuery;
    /* The actual kendo plugin stuff...*/
  }
);
```

This is because calling noConflict means the global $ and jQuery variables get unbound. There for you have to explicitly specify the local variables you want to bind to jQuery or it wont work. Most plugins expect the jQuery variable to defined, but it could assume $ as well.

P.S. Even if the plugin is AMD enabled and has a define clause in it, it is possible that the plugin needs some modifications to work with private jQuery. It seems some plugins do not use the local variables to which the dependencies are bound to and passed down to the plugins on the define declaration. Instead they use whatever it is that is or isn't publicly defined (e.g. backbone). So they are using the define clause just as a way of stating what are the dependencies and to make sure requriejs loads some form of jQuery, but they don't actually bother using them. This, however, is not the the case with jQuery.